# Python pytesseract : Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm using colab, and this is my code

```
extractedInformation = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("/content/1.jpeg"),lang='chi_tra')
print(extractedInformation)
```

and it shows

```
TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/chi_tra.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'chi_tra\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

But when I set the **lang='eng'**, it's all working.
I've tried to set

```
!export TESSDATA_PREFIX="/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata"
```

to point my tessdata directory, but it can't work.
And I checked the available languages by this:

```
tesseract --list-langs
```

and

```
List of available languages (3):
chi_tra
osd
eng
```

Doesn't that means that I can set the lang='chi_tra'?
That confused me.
Is it a problem with the version of traineddata?